# Convert ListView SubItem to int

Tags: c#, listview

Currently, my program loads data into memory, and adds integers to a listview. I'm trying to get the selected list view item's value though when I use:

```
int offset = Convert.ToInt64(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].ToString());
```

I get a weird exception when trying to use it though. For example, I'm trying to send a MessageBox with the int's value(with .ToString()) and it throws some weird exception.

Also I would like to note SelectedItems[0] works when just grabbing the string.

Comment: well, seeing how he tries to stuff a 64bit integer in a 32bit integer I think it is the NeedMoreSpaceException :-)

Comment: Why not setting a break-point in your code-behind to watch the subitem value?

Comment: I changed the int part from long because I thought I had a different line of code in. It was originally a long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### OOpz, you forgot `SubItems[2].Text`

---

You need to use the `ListViewSubItem.Text` property

```
Int64 offset = Int64.Parse(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text);
Int64 offset = Convert.ToInt64(listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text);
```

---

`listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].ToString()` would return something like "`ListViewSubItem: {the_subitem_text}`"

`listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].ToString()` by default return the `Object.ToString()`

Comment: It works but since I'm trying to use a BinaryReader, it throws a NullReference exception.

Comment: by nature of exception : NullReference seems like u havent created instance of BinaryReader or may be some object involved!

Comment: can paste the exact exception message?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ZGPD.Form1.listView1_MouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) in C:\C#\ZGPD 1.0\ZGPD\ZGPD\Form1.cs:line 169

Comment: When it's double clicked i'm wanting it to read that line of the file.

Comment: Reader.Close();  <<--- under openFileToolStripMenuItem_Click , if u close the reader how are you supposed to read it?

Comment: remove that line, and i guess everything will be fine!